# NameError: line is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my short code:

```
import random
lines = list()
random.shuffle(line)
for i, line in enumerate(open('Filename.txt')):
    if i >= 21 and i < 89:
       print (line, end='')
```

I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/macbookpro/Desktop/Dictionary2.py", line 3, in <module>
random.shuffle(line)
NameError: name 'line' is not defined
```

Now I understand the error, but I am having difficulty fixing it. When I comment out random.shuffle(line), my output prints successfully. But when I try to randomize it, random shuffle does not recognize 'line'. Why does print recognize 'line' but random.shuffle does not? How can I alter my code so that it does?

[EDIT] When I adjust the code by changing 'line' to 'lines' I now get the following NameError:

```
  import random
  lines = list(lines)
  random.shuffle(lines)
  for i, line in enumerate(open('Filename.txt')):
      if i >= 21 and i < 89:
      print (line, end='')

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/macbookpro/Desktop/Dictionary2.py", line 2, in <module>
lines = list(lines)
NameError: name 'lines' is not defined
```

random.shuffle is still not reading what I put in there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have `lines = list()` then try to shuffle `line` which doesn't exist. Simple typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the variable `line` is not declared before you try to `shuffle()` it. Instead the variable `lines` is declared.

Perhaps you mean:

```
lines = list()
random.shuffle(lines)
```

However, this achieves nothing since shuffling an empty sequence will not do anything.

Now, `line` is assigned to in the for loop and so it is available within the body of the loop.

What you probably need to do is something like this:

```
import random

with open('Filename.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    random.shuffle(lines)
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if i >= 21 and i < 89:
            print (line, end='')
```

Here the contents of the file are first read into a list, shuffled, and this shuffled list is iterated over.

The purpose of your code is somewhat elusive. Since the lines have been randomised, there is no difference between selecting line numbers between the range 21 to 88, or selecting any other range of 68 lines, e.g. you could just grab the first 68 lines after shuffling:

```
with open('Filename.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    random.shuffle(lines)
    print(*lines[:68], sep='')
```